# Rails: using same model in concurrent threads raises `uninitialized constant ModelName`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multithreading, concurrency, rake

`uninitialized constant ModelName` is returned when two concurrent threads try to access ModelName.

Same error happens with a rake `multitask` if two of its tasks try to access one model or class at the same time.

It is not a database issue, my pool size is large enough and the error occurs even for regular classes with no database.

Is this possible to make sure two concurrent threads could access the same class or model at the same time? I could run them in two different processes but I want to make sure they have access to a shared variable.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a Mutex. 
I had the same issue with class. 
Something like that should solve the problem:

```
require 'thread'
mutex = Mutex.new
mutex.synchronize do
  MyClass.class_method(param)
end
```